# cmd abrindo junto do .py executavel

Tags: python

Estou praticando criação de aplicações usando python, E estou tentando dar um jeito do Promt não abrir em segundo plano toda vez que executo a aplicação, alguém pode me ajudar com isso (ainda sou leigo no assunto)

Comment: Sua questão precisa de mais exclarecimentos, quais bibliotecas, qual código está usando, mas geralmente se está usando Pyinstaller `--noconsole` deve resolver.
[Como não perguntar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1)

Answer (score -1):

Para que o prompt de comando não abra junto ao seu arquivo .py executável, você pode transformá-lo em um arquivo executável (.exe) usando a ferramenta pyinstaller.

Para fazer isso, instale o pyinstaller usando o pip install e em seguida, execute o seguinte comando para criar um arquivo executável a partir do seu arquivo .py:

pyinstaller --onefile nome_do_seu_arquivo.py

Isso criará um arquivo executável .exe na pasta "dist" na raiz do seu projeto. Agora você pode clicar neste arquivo para executar sua aplicação sem o prompt de comando sendo aberto.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).